# sed replacement for a string

Tags: linux, string, sed

```
(declare-const buabor Real)
```

which I want to replace as

```
(declare-fun buabor () Real)
```

can it be done with sed?

I tried

```
sed 's/(declare-const\s([a-z])\s(Real))/(declare-fun\s\2\(\)\3/)g'
```

but was not able to get the result
any help would be great

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/(declare-const buabor Real)/(declare-fun buabor () Real)/' file`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do (assuming `GNU sed` as `\s` is used):

```
sed 's/(declare-const\s\([a-z]*\)/(declare-fun \1()/'
```

- By default, BRE is used, so `(` and `)` will be matched literally in search section. See also [BRE-vs-ERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE) section in the manual
- `\(` and `\)` will then become capture group
- `[a-z]*` will match zero or more lowercase alphabets
- rest of the line need not be matched and used in replacement section as it isn't modified

A few more observations:

- `(` and `)` aren't special in replacement section
- `\s` is again not special in replacement section, will insert `s`